# selected item to Textbox-Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in my WPF application. When it is selected i am going to display the value in the 6th column in a Text box. So I have binded the selected item of `datagrid` to the `textbox`

**Code:**

```
 myTextBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, 
           (new Binding("SelectedItem." + dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header)
            { 
               ElementName = "dataGrid1" 
            }));
```

In my code behind in my Xaml, But it is throwing some Xaml Parse Exception saying

```
<TextBlock Name="myTextBox1" />
```

**Error:**

```
Set connectionId threw an exception.'whose inner excpetion is 
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' 
to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'."}
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: if i understood correctly ,you want show the value in textbox but here i see your taking the header.

Comment: @Kiran1016 : yeah i need to display value in my textbox of the selected column eith the header name dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header

Comment: (new Binding("SelectedItem." + dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header) { ElementName = "dataGrid1" }) this will return textblock but you are trying to convert it to textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 myTextBox1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, (new Binding("SelectedItem." +   dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header) { ElementName = "dataGrid1" }))
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
dataGrid1.Columns[5].Header
```

You need to use

```
dataGrid1.Columns[5].HeaderText
```

Hopefully that will work